# Streetview doen't appear sometimes in Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Here is my code

```
panoramaOptions = {
enableCloseButton : true,
visible : false
};

myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"), panoramaOptions);

var mapOptions = {
    center: currentCenter,
    zoom: defaultZoom,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    overviewMapControl: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    streetView : myPano
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);  

map.setStreetView(myPano);

google.maps.event.addListener(map,"click", function(e) {
map.setCenter(e.latLng);
myPano.setPosition(e.latLng);

if (marker != null) {
        marker.setMap(null);
}

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("http:///maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/cb/man_arrow-0.png"),
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        position: e.latLng
});

marker.setMap(map);
myPano.setVisible(true);
});
```

Now the problem is that sometimes the streetview doesn't come. How to solve this?

Comment: what do you mean by "sometimes the streetview doesn't come"?

Comment: @geocodezip By sometimes i mean it is displaying grey as if it is not refreshed. Also some times when this happens then i take my pointer on the Map and it appears. Did u get me?

Comment: What I've found in the past is sometimes you need to wait for the map to fully load before trying to load the streetview.  Use something like jQuery's `$(document).ready()` before creating your streetview

Comment: @duncan thanks for the tip. What about the map layout, should it be absolute or relative?

Comment: I think absolute, although I'm not so sure about this

Comment: I am having the same problem. Any resolution?